# How to test a watch on a computed property linked to a store getter, with jest and vue-test-utils?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, watch, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue component.
My component have a computed property that refer to a getter of a vuex store.

[image: The vuex getter]

I use a watch to perform some action when this getter is updated.

[image: the watch]

I want to test the watch using jest and vue-test-utils.

How can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Found an hack here [How to test Vue watcher that watches a computed property from VueX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49431735/how-to-test-vue-watcher-that-watches-a-computed-property-from-vuex?rq=2) :

```
wrapper.vm.$options.watch.event.call(wrapper.vm, event)
```